# PHP extension version inconsistencies; a more reliable way?

Tags: php, versioning, php-extension

Having run the following:

```
foreach(get_loaded_extensions() as $name){
    $extensions[strtolower($name)] = phpversion($name);
}
var_dump($extensions);
```

I notice that some of the loaded extensions don't show a version, having false instead, for instance:

```
'pcre' => boolean false
```

However, when I hit up `phpinfo()`, it shows a version number: [image]

Why isn't the `phpversion()` function fetching the correct results? I understand in this instance I could simply pull `PCRE_VERSION`, but needing to do so for some but not all extensions is silly; `gd` shows false too.

---

**Edit**: Fix;

```
foreach(get_loaded_extensions() as $name){
    $extensions[strtolower($name)] = phpversion($name);
}
$extensions = array_replace($extensions, array(
    'iconv' => ICONV_VERSION,
    'pcre' => PCRE_VERSION,
    'libxml' => LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION,
    'gd' => GD_VERSION,
    // others i may be missing, will get to it
));
```

---

**Edit**: Here's the full dump and the `phpinfo()` output, just for giggles:

```
array
  'core' => string '5.3.8' (length=5)
  'bcmath' => boolean false
  'calendar' => boolean false
  'com_dotnet' => string '0.1' (length=3)
  'ctype' => boolean false
  'date' => string '5.3.8' (length=5)
  'ereg' => boolean false
  'filter' => string '0.11.0' (length=6)
  'ftp' => boolean false
  'hash' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  'iconv' => boolean false
  'json' => string '1.2.1' (length=5)
  'mcrypt' => boolean false
  'spl' => string '0.2' (length=3)
  'odbc' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  'pcre' => boolean false
  'reflection' => string '$Revision: 313665 $' (length=19)
  'session' => boolean false
  'standard' => string '5.3.8' (length=5)
  'mysqlnd' => string 'mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 310735 $' (length=50)
  'tokenizer' => string '0.1' (length=3)
  'zip' => string '1.9.1' (length=5)
  'zlib' => string '1.1' (length=3)
  'libxml' => boolean false
  'dom' => string '20031129' (length=8)
  'pdo' => string '1.0.4dev' (length=8)
  'bz2' => boolean false
  'simplexml' => string '0.1' (length=3)
  'wddx' => boolean false
  'xml' => boolean false
  'xmlreader' => string '0.1' (length=3)
  'xmlwriter' => string '0.1' (length=3)
  'apache2handler' => boolean false
  'phar' => string '2.0.1' (length=5)
  'mbstring' => boolean false
  'exif' => string '1.4 $Id: exif.c 314376 2011-08-06 14:47:44Z felipe $' (length=52)
  'gd' => boolean false
  'gettext' => boolean false
  'imap' => boolean false
  'mysql' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  'mysqli' => string '0.1' (length=3)
  'pdo_mysql' => string '1.0.2' (length=5)
  'pdo_odbc' => string '1.0.1' (length=5)
  'pdo_sqlite' => string '1.0.1' (length=5)
  'soap' => boolean false
  'sockets' => boolean false
  'sqlite' => string '2.0-dev' (length=7)
  'sqlite3' => string '0.7-dev' (length=7)
  'tidy' => string '2.0' (length=3)
  'xmlrpc' => string '0.51' (length=4)
  'mhash' => boolean false
  'xdebug' => string '2.1.1' (length=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a version of the shared library installed in the system, not the extension itself?

Comment: That's weird. http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/info.c#92 prints the `zend_module->version` and then phpversion http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/info.c#1263 calls http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_API.c#3077 which also returns the `module->version`. I am curious too.

Comment: Is your PCRE statically linked in to PHP, or loaded dynamically? I suspect it isn't actually a loaded extension when it's compiled in.

Comment: @Phil Lello - Ah, good point, perhaps that's why. I suppose I should accommodate for such circumstances in a dump, as with `gd` and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> phpversion() returns the version of that extension, or FALSE if there
>   is no version information associated or the extension isn't enabled.

What you saw in `phpinfo()` is not the version information of the extension but the c-client version of the library. The `prce` extension itself has no version information.

Comment: Thanks @xdazz - I'll resort to checking certain extensions (*such as `pcre` and `gd`*) manually; see edit for fix (*above my obstructing inclusion of a `phpinfo()` dump*).